# Monitoring files for changes, but only changes to the content (not last modified date)?

Tags: powershell

I have tinkered with a small script that monitors a folder and alerts if there is a change with that folder. Here is what I have so far:

```
$folder = 'folder\to\monitor' 

$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{IncludeSubdirectories = $true;NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'}

Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Changed -SourceIdentifier FileChanged1 -Action { 
$path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath 
$changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType 
$timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated 
$datestamp = get-date -uformat "%Y-%m-%d@%H-%M-%S" 
$Computer = get-content env:computername 
$Body = " $path on $Computer was $changeType at $timeStamp" 
$PIECES=$path.split("\") 
$newfolder=$PIECES[-2] 
Out-File -FilePath c:\Scripts\config_changes.txt -Append -InputObject " $path on $Computer was $changeType at $timeStamp" 
Send-MailMessage -To "email@domain.com" -From "email@domain.com" -Subject $Body -SmtpServer "192.168.#.##" -Body " " 
#Copy-Item $path "c:\scripts\versions\$newfolder" 
#Rename-Item "c:\Scripts\Versions\$newfolder\web.config" "web.config-$datestamp" 
#Remove-Item -path "c:\Scripts\Versions\$newfolder\web.config" -force}

# To stop the monitoring, run the following commands: 
# Unregister-Event FileChanged1
```

However, I am wanting to make the "criteria" for a file change a little more specific. From what research I've done, the FileSystemWatcher.Notify filter limits me to File Name, Last Write, etc. What I would like to do is check to see if any changes have been made to the *content* of the file. If none of the content has changed, then I don't want it to alert.

The file constantly gets overwritten, even if there are no changes, so the modified date continues to change even if there is no content change.

Comment: Can't you use a NotifyFilter on Size? So add Size to your filters when you create your FileSystemWatcher?

Comment: You could run an MD5 or CRC on the file, and check that every time the lastwritetime changes.

Comment: @DavidBrabant I would guess that small trivial changes might not change the size like 0 to a 1.